# Primitive of $\frac{\ln (x^2 + 1)}{2x^2 \ln (x + 1)}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I want to integrate $ \displaystyle \int \dfrac{\ln (x^2 + 1)}{2x^2 \ln (x + 1)} \ dx $

I've tried a $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x} $ substitution, but that complicates the integrand.

Mathematica's online integrator could not integrate it, however I have heard that sometimes it is possible to evaluate integrals that Mathematica cannot.

Comment on the edit:

In light of the comment on the definite integral's convergence, I have modified the question to an indefinite integral. Apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: are you sure that your integral is convergent?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Apologies, I now think that it does not converge. However I am still interested in the integral so I will modify the question to address the indefinite integral.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder where people get their strange integrals from...

Comment: Maple can't integrate it either

Comment: The integrand function behaves like $\frac{1}{2x}$ in a neighbourhood of zero, hence it is not integrable.

Comment: Try $ x=\tan \theta $